# How to convert url to regex statement

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I want to use ACL for authorization (https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl) but i can't use it with complex urls like `http://domain.com/api/v1/resource/:id1/anotherResource/:id2`

Using node js, express can handle finding right function from the url from request's originalUrl or something else. I need to put regular expressions statements of requested urls into configuration of ACL.

I debugged express step by step and found regex form of url on 84th line of Layer.js but I need to know every regex form of url to use ACL module as a middleware.

Is there any way to get regexp string (like in the picture below) of url to use in middleware?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) module which is used [internally by expressjs](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L5) (actually you were very close to finding it while debugging)

Comment: I've seen it but I couldn't convert the _request.originalUrl to proper function of express. I want to write a middleware function that can sense which function will work.

Comment: Maybe I could help with that. What would be the purpose of the middleware - you converting the request url to a regexp or matching it agains some other data?

Comment: I've REST functions for different addresses. And I need to authorize users can/not get access to this addresses. To do this I want to use this for authorize `route('/api/v1/resource1/:id1/resource2/:id2').all(function(_request, _response, _next){ //authorize and pass or not _next func })` But the acl middleware which I'm using can't resolve this kind urls (like: '/api/v1/resource1/:id1/resource2/:id2'). It only gets like this '/api/v1/resource' and this is not sufficient for me.But if I could resolve the requested url as regexp I can pass `'/api/v1/resource1/:id1/resource2/:id2'` link to ACL.